# I can only find two formats in import/export

Tags: export, import

I can only find two formats in import/export: Collada & Alembic.

I've checked the add-ons; all the add-ons like fbx, obj (wavefront) are turned on but still not showing in the import/export box. How do I get them to show up?

Comment: Disabling Load UI may help. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149008/add-ons-dont-show-in-menus-blender-2-8-mac

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue, to fix it I had to uncheck "Filter Add-ons" under the first tab in the outliner.

Maybe its the answer but could be something else, hope this helps.