# Add-ons don't show in menus - Blender 2,8-Mac

Tags: add-on

I have a number of add-ons installed in 2.8, import/export, mesh, etc. They don't show up in the appropriate menus, however. For instance, I have the 'official' add-ons: BVH, FBX, STL, OBJ and VRML2 installed and enabled but when I go to the import menu all I am offered is Collada(dae) and Alembic (abc) which are not actually even add-ons.

Am I missing some 'switch' or something or is this a bug? 
I can't believe this is general behaviour or there would be more 'noise' in these forums. The only thing I see is a 4 month old - and unanswered - query which sounds similar to mine!

Answer (score 1):

When you're loading the project file through *File > Open* uncheck *Load UI* and you should see all your add-ons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I decided to try the latest 'beta' version 2.8.1 (before considering entering a bug report) and everything works perfectly with this version!
I don't know if 2.8 didn't install correctly or this version 'fixes' a bug (there was nothing in the release notes to suggest a fix).